# Need to grep all comments from an SQL file

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep

I have a file containing SQLs, it has few create table commands followed by some comments on table/columns. File text looks like this

```
create table abc
(col1, ..,..);

comment on table abc is 'This is a single line comment';
comment on column abc.col1 is 'This is a multi-line comment.
One more line of description here';
comment on column abc.col2 is 'This is a single line comment';

create table mno
(col1, ..,..);

comment on table mno is 'This is a multi-line comment.
One more line of description here';
comment on column mno.col1 is 'This is a single line comment';
collect statistics on mno column (column1);
```

Simple grep command fails to catch multi-line comments. I understand,I need to print all lines which start with "comment on" text till first occurance of ";" .. Incase of multi-line comments this will also mean printing in-between lines which does not start with "comment on" statement.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Could you post some tries you already made?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Orignal format:

```
awk -v RS=';' '/comment on.*/' sqlfile
```

Or in Single line:

```
awk -v RS=';' '/comment on.*/{$1=$1;print $0}' sqlfile
```

Comment: Thanks @PS. ; It gave me o/p exactly I wanted :)

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^comment on.*;\s*$/b;/^comment on/!d;:a;n;/;\s*$/!ba' file
```

Print single line comments. Delete any other lines that are not multiline comments.

This might be written more tersely as:

```
sed '/^comment on/{:a;/;\s*$/{p;d};n;ba};d' file
```

Comment: This could be done without branch command (`b`)... This may break if a comment contain a `;` at end of one line. Add `\o47` before `;` to be correct! Anyway, your script seem quicker than mine.

Comment: Thanks @potong, Thanks for your valuable time and help. I have accepted answer by PS. as I find it simplest.

Answer (score 1):

### Simply, using [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
sed -ne '/comment/{:;/\o47;$/!{n;b};p}' < path/filename
```

Where:

- if a line do contain `comment`

  - set a branch point
  - check if line terminate with `';`
  - if else

    - print current buffer and get next line
    - branch to previously set branch point
  - print current buffer
- with `-n` switch, drop everything else

This will print single line comments **and** multiline comments:

```
comment on table abc is 'This is a single line comment';
comment on column abc.col1 is 'This is a multi-line comment.
One more line of description here';
comment on column abc.col2 is 'This is a single line comment';
comment on table mno is 'This is a multi-line comment.
One more line of description here';
comment on column mno.col1 is 'This is a single line comment';
```

#### Merging lines

If you want all comments in on line, you have to merge lines in hold buffer, by using `N` instead of `n`, then replace newlines by spaces:

```
sed -ne '/comment/{:;/\o47;\s*$/!{N;b};s/\n\s*/ /;p}' <file
```

Comment: As [@potong](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43863821/1765658) suggest, you could add `\s*` between `;` and `$` to get lines containing trailing spaces: `sed -n '/comment/{:;/\o47;\s*$/!{n;b};p}'`

Comment: Thanks @F. Hauri, it gave me required output. I am using answer provided by PS. (using awk)due to simplicity. It was good to know sed can do same thing as well :)

Comment: @PankajK by using [tag:sed], you could merge lines too ;-)  I prefer generaly `sed` to `awk` because it's lighter and more frequently installed in poor configurations.

Answer (score 0):

I would use sed for this scope.

This command does the trick:

```
sed -e 's/comment\(.*\);/\1/' sql.txt
```

Please replace sql.txt with your actual file name.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It didn't gave me correct o/p but appreciate your timely suggestion :)

Comment: what are you getting? knowing this would help everyone to help you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try deleting the newlines, then replacing ; with newlines:

```
$ cat /tmp/test | tr -d '\n' | tr ';' '\n' | grep '^[[:space:]]*comment on'
comment on table abc is 'This is a single line comment'
comment on column abc.col1 is 'This is a multi-line comment.One more line of description here'
comment on column abc.col2 is 'This is a single line comment'
comment on table mno is 'This is a multi-line comment.One more line of description here'
comment on column mno.col1 is 'This is a single line comment'
```